# Multiple concurrent event handling in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to handle multiple concurrent events using jQuery but I am having problems finely managing when the events are fired.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">Edit some content</div>
    <button id="button" type="button">Click the button</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button').click(function (e) {
          alert('I have been clicked.');
        });
        $('#edit').blur(function (e) {
          alert('I have been edited.')
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What I wish to achieve is for the content of the DIV to be edited by a user and when the button is clicked, for that event to be raised before the blur event on the DIV. It may be the case that the button is never clicked in which case the blur event may fire on its own. As you can see using the code above, once you edit the content and click the button only the blur event is fired.

Please can someone advise how I may achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: As a sidenote: blur() is not everywhere supported for <div> elements. Older browsers support this event only for input elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One — admittingly very hacky — way would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var buttonClicked = false;
    $('#button').bind('click', function(e) {
        buttonClicked = true;
        alert('I have been clicked.');
    });
    $('#edit').bind('blur', function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!buttonClicked) alert('I have been edited.');
            buttonClicked = false;
        }, 100);

    });
});
```

This example doesn't prevent the firing of the event, though. It only handles the callback.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Dp6b5/1/
You can adjust the timeout delay and don't necessarily have to use `bind` in this case either.

It's an interesting question, but I don't see any "proper" way to handle this atm., since the `blur` event is de facto fired before the `click`. Maybe someone else has a better idea I can't see atm..

Comment: You need to also reset buttonClicked to false in the blur conditional, but otherwise though hacky this works. +

Comment: Very true — I'm updating the example. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, that should do the trick if there is no neater way to deal with the issue. An 'else' case for when buttonClicked is true within the blur handler also lets me manage the case when both the blur and click events were raised.